# Using one form for two similar models

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class BaseAddress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True



class ProfileBilling(BaseAddress):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(
        Profile, related_name='billing_info')

class OrderBilling(BaseAddress):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, related_name='billing')
    name_on_card = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #card_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    #    choices=CARD_TYPE, default=0)
    #card_number = models.CharField(
    #    max_length=16, default=0)
    expire_month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=MONTHS, null=True, default=0)
    expire_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=YEARS, null=True, default=1960)
```

When customers input a billing address, I want to save it in OrderBilling, but I also want to save it in ProfileBilling as their most recent billing address. How do I do so?

How do I go about using forms to save billing address in two different tables when the OrderBilling and ProfileBilling have most of the same fields...?

How do I do this in Django?

Here is my OrderBilling form:

```
class OrderBillingForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = OrderBilling
    exclude = ('order',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OrderBillingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['address'].required = True
    self.fields['city'].required = True
    self.fields['state'] = USStateField()
    self.fields['zip_code'] = us.USZipCodeField()
    self.fields['phone'].required = False
    self.fields['expire_month'].required = False
    self.fields['expire_year'].required = False

def clean(self):
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `save()` method, But the smarter way in your case would be using [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal for this purpose.

After a`OrderBilling` get saved, You can save its data into `ProfileBilling` too.

look at some example on google search in case to be familiar with post_save signal,

like:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/2m88qTrqnM8
- http://www.djangofoo.com/85/signal-connect-disconnect-django-signals
- etc...

then Easyily in your post_save receiver|callback funcstion get the `OrderBilling` instance

```
orderbil_instance = kwargs['instance']
```

And create your ProfileBilling from its data

```
ProfileBilling.objects.create(name=orderbil_instance.name, ....)
```

Something like on `post_save` signal receiver

```
def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    # Getting OrderBilling instance which get saved just now
    orderbil_instance = kwargs['instance']
    # Save the data into new ProfileBilling
    ProfileBilling.objects.create(name=orderbil_instance.name, ....)
```

Comment: How do I use post_save to do this? I know I call post_save(savetoprofile, sender=OrderBilling) but how do I use the arguments in savetoprofile to save to ProfileBilling?

Comment: I did the following:

    def save_to_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        ProfileBilling.create(
            address=instance.address, address_2=instance.address_2,
            city=instance.city, state=instance.state, zip_code=instance.zip_code)

    post_save(save_to_profile, sender=OrderBilling)